# WPF Charting Toolkit: How to add different labels to different data points in a line series

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I have a line chart where i have the itemsource bound to a list. Is it possible to attach different labels to each data point?

```
<Grid>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="LineChart1" Width="880" Height="400" Margin="69,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>
            <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Name="Line1" DependentValuePath="Value" 
                                        IndependentValuePath="Key" 
                                        IsSelectionEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SourceList, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <chartingToolkit:DataPointSeries.DataPointStyle>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource NewDataPointStyle}"
                        TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint}">
                    </Style>
                </chartingToolkit:DataPointSeries.DataPointStyle>
            </chartingToolkit:LineSeries> 
         </chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>           
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>        
</Grid>
```